# How to check if a specific digit is in an integer

Tags: python

I want to check if, for example, the digit '2' is in 4059304593.
My aim is to then check if there are any of the digits 1-9 not in my integer. This is what I have tried:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(100):
        num = str(i^j)
        one_count = 0
        two_count = 0
        for k in xrange(len(num)):
            if num[k] == 1:
                one_count += 1
            if num[k] == 2:
                two_count += 1
```

Then my "counts" would go all the way down to nine_count, and if any of the counts are 0, then that digit isn't in 'num'. From what I've read on these sites, my script would be inefficient - can someone point out a better way?

Comment: Why not just something like ```str(digit_to_search) in str(searched_number)```? (aka linear search within a string = list of chars)

Comment: I'm sorry but the digit "2" is not in that number. What is it you're seeking again?

Comment: Why not convert to a string then a set, then perform a difference?

Comment: Basically I want something that takes a number as an input, then returns as an output the digits(1-9) which aren't in that number (if any)

Comment: You only want to check if *any* of the nonzero digits 1-9 are not in your integer? You don't need to know which digits, and you don't need to know the count of their occurrence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This "digit" thing calls for a string approach, not a numeric one (reminds me of some [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) puzzles).

I'd create a `set` out of the digits of your number first (removing duplicates at the same time)

```
s = set(str(4059304593))
```

then to check for a digit:

```
print('2' in s)
```

(note that `in` for a `set` is performant)

then, to check whether `s` contains all the `013456789` digits:

```
print(s.issuperset("013456789"))
```

(if this must be done multiple times, it may be worth to create a `set` with the string, `issuperset` will work faster)

Comment: Interestingly, making a set may not be helpful unless the number is very long: the breakeven point is between 37k-75k digits: [repl.it](https://repl.it/FvqI/3)

Comment: the hashing & set algorithm takes time before you can notice it, yes

Comment: Jean, will this work for all strings right ? To find if something is missing a character ? For both python 2 and 3 ?

Comment: @TonyTannous yes for all your questions. I tend to write version-agnostic code when possible.

Comment: I am blind. I wrote 0 instead of o and it returned false... couldnt see why. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your number to a string, then to a set to get the unique digits.

You just have to iterate over digits in 0-9 to find the ones not present in your original number :

```
>>> set(map(int,str(4059304593)))
set([0, 9, 3, 4, 5])
>>> digits = _
>>> [i for i in range(10) if i not in digits]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: you don't even have to convert back to string. Just work with characters,

Comment: not sure. check my answer to see what I mean. And BTW I learned something about the `_`. Nice! of course: out of votes & repcapped: I can't vote and you can't give me rep either :) But the `set` approach is good no matter what. The neat part is that you can do `2 in digits`, whereas I have to do `"2" in digits`

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
j = 0
nL = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
n = 1004 #number
while n:
    i = n%10
    nL[i] = 1
    n //= 10
```

**OUT**

`nL = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Explanation:
if `nL[i]` is 1, then the i-th digit is in `n`

Comment: I'd do `n//=10` (integer & in-place division) so it works with both python 2 & 3.

Comment: tricked you: I'm out of votes today :) Next nitpick: `while (n!=0):` => `while n:`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre :) it is ok. I am used to provide answers that work and get downvotes instead of upvotes :P. Well I am not out of votes and I did +1 for you approach to handle it as a string. And I edited again :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to find out which digits aren't in your number:

```
def not_in_number(n):
    return {*range(10)} - {*map(int, {*str(n)})}
```

Usage:

```
>>> not_in_number(4059304593)
{1, 2, 6, 7, 8}
```

This takes the set of digits (`{*range(10)}`) and substracts from it the set of digits of your number (`{*map(int, {*str(n)})}`), created by mapping the set of digit characters to integers. If you find the [`{*...}` notation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) confusing, you can always use `set(...)` instead, which will also work for Python 2.7+:

```
def not_in_number(n):
    return set(range(10)) - set(map(int, set(str(n))))
```

Comment: I haven't seen such notation before. I tried copying your function, but it produced a syntax error

Comment: Ah ok, mistake on my end then.

Comment: @mrnovice Ah, sorry, I should have seen that you're using xrange. It will work if you use `set()` though; editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `-` with sets:

```
set('0123456789') - set(str(4059304593))
```

Result are all digits that aren't in your integer:

> {'2', '7', '1', '6', '8'}