# Python for beginners.Range, exclude specific numbers

Tags: python, range

New to Python here!
Can somebody please help me with a small task ?
I need to write an algorithm that can print all numbers between 0 and 100. With exception of numbers that are divisible by 10 like 10,20,30,40... etc
Also all numbers that contain 3 in them , like 3,13,23,30,33 ...etc

I got the divisible by 10 part, but excluding all numbers containing 3 got me stuck :(

Please Help!!!!

```
for i in range (1,100):
    if i %10 and i[0] != 3:
        pass
        print (i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a specific digit is in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426242/how-to-check-if-a-specific-digit-is-in-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
for i in range (1,100):
    if i %10 and '3' not in str(i):
        print(i)
```

This loop will not print numbers that the number modulo 10 return 0 and it will convert each number to string to check if it's containing 3 inits.
And you can do it in one line with list comprehension and unpacking the list into a print statement.

```
print(*[i for i in range (1,100) if i %10 and '3' not in str(i)], sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to understand everything here (given you said you are new to python, thought to add few details):

range function in python actually has following structure:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

It will print all numbers 'starting from the start point' and ending at step-1)

so a `range(0,6,1)` will return `0,1,2,3,4,5`

The function by default takes 0 as start point and 1 as step size, so that:

```
range(100) #will return all numbers from 0-99
```

So message to be taken is that 'Stop' parameter is a must to provide to range function.

As you must have noted, loops or functions do not follow the braces convention and rather `colon (:)` followed by **proper indentation** is the norm for the same.

Coming to your first condition i%10 (which will return zero for numbers divisible by 10), however i[0] should return an error given i is an integer and it is not subscriptable. ***But note that if i was a string, then i can be subscripted and i[0] would return the first character of i.***

e.g

```
 i=10
i[0] will throw error

i='10'
i[0] will return '1'
```

In order for you to check whether i contains a particular digit, you have various options at hand. Simplest as suggested by Leo does the following:

Convert i into string by using `str(i)`. Then as I said, a string is subscriptable (unlike an integer), you can actually go through each character of the string str(i) by using **in**, such that `if letter in string` will search for a given letter in each character of the string. A match will return 1.

Hence `if '3' in str(i)` will **return 1** if str(i) contains string '3' (quotes define the nature of input variable here as string).

and `if '3' not in str(i)` will **return 1** for all cases where 3 is not in the str(i).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `i[0]` is wrong, `i` is an int object, it is not subscriptable, you don't need to index it again, you can directly use the value from it:

```
for i in range (1,100):
    if i %10 == 0 or '3' in str(i):
        continue
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

just search for 3 in the number string and now works cool

```
for i in range (1,100):
    if i %10 and str(i).find("3") == -1:
        pass
        print (i)
```